# Xamarin Android Emulator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу запустить эмулятор Android в Xamarin. Образ системы устройства "Phone" является неполным и не может быть запущен.

Comment: `Образ системы устройства "Phone" является неполным` — а вы не допускаете вероятности того, что это так и есть на самом деле???

Comment: Я не понимаю, что значит неполный